# How can I 301 redirect an entire subfolder to the home page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, magento, mod-alias

I am trying to redirect a subfolder as well as anything after it to the home page.

For example:

`example.com/subfolder/extra-stuff` > `example.com`

The `extra-stuff` is constantly changing and auto generated, so I want the redirect to remove that as well.

I am using:

```
Redirect 301 /subfolder(.*) http://www.example.com
```

However, this will result in `http://www.example.com/extra-stuff`.

Is there a way I can say if `/subfolder(and anything else after subfolder)` redirect to home?

Answer (score 2):

The `Redirect` directive uses simple prefix-matching and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL (which is what you are seeing here). However, the `Redirect` directive also does not support regex syntax, so a "pattern" like `(.*)` on the end will actually match the literal characters `(`, `.`, `*` and `)` - which shouldn't have worked in your example?!

You'll need to use `RedirectMatch` instead (also part of mod_alias), which uses regular expression matching (not simple prefix matching). Note also, that whilst the `Redirect` directive only matches whole path-segments, the `RedirectMatch` has no such restriction, so we must build that into the regex.

For example, to match the `/subfolder` only and all requests within that subfolder you would need to do the following:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subfolder($|/) http://www.example.com/
```

Any request for `/subfolder` (or anything that starts `/subfolder/`) will be redirected to `http://www.example.com/` exactly.

The additional `($|/)` on the regex is necessary to prevent matching files in the root that simply start with `/subfolder`, eg. `/subfolderfoo.html` (which may or may not be an issue in your environment). The original `Redirect` directive would also not match such requests.

You'll need to clear your browser catch before testing, since 301 (permanent) redirects are cached persistently by the browser. (Test first with 302 - temporary - redirects to avoid potential caching issues.)

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

---

You tagged your question "Magento" (which is probably using mod_rewrite). You should note, however, if you are already using mod_rewrite for rewrites/redirects then you should probably be using mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias (`Redirect` and `RedirectMatch`) to do this redirect, since you can potentially get conflicts.

For example, the equivalent mod_rewrite directive would be:

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder($|/) http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Note there is no slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. This would need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule